# Kafka wiith nestjs error: KafkaJSProtocolError: This server does not host this topic-partition

Tags: apache-kafka, nest, kafkajs

I have a kafka cluster that I run using docker compose:

```yaml
broker1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.4.0
    hostname: broker1
    container_name: broker1
    depends_on:
      - controller
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    environment:
      KAFKA_NODE_ID: 1
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: 'CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT'
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'PLAINTEXT://broker1:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092'
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: 'broker'
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: '2@controller:9093'
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: 'PLAINTEXT://broker1:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://0.0.0.0:9092'
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: 'PLAINTEXT'
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: 'CONTROLLER'
      KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: '/tmp/kraft-combined-logs'
      CLUSTER_ID: 'MkU3OEVBNTcwNTJENDM2Qk'
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      

  controller:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.4.0
    hostname: controller
    container_name: controller
    ports:
      - "9093:9093"
      - "9102:9102"
    environment:
      KAFKA_NODE_ID: 2
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9102
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: 'controller'
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: '2@controller:9093'
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: 'CONTROLLER://controller:9093'
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: 'PLAINTEXT'
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: 'CONTROLLER'
      KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: '/tmp/kraft-controller-logs'
      CLUSTER_ID: 'MkU3OEVBNTcwNTJENDM2Qk'
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'true'
```

notice that `KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'true'` which means kafka is configured to create topics automatically.

My nest client configuation:

```js
const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(
    AppModule,
    {
      transport: Transport.KAFKA,
      options: {
        client: {
          brokers: ['localhost:9092']
        }
      },
      consumer: {
        groupId: 'my-consumer-group',
        allowAutoTopicCreation: true
      }
    }
)
```

For consuming specific topic i use the `@EventPattern` decorator.

I expect that the application will create the topics that my consumer is consuming, but instead i get this error:

```
ERROR [Connection] Response Meadata(key: 3, version: 6) {"timestamp": "2023-08-09T10:20:17.462Z", "logger": "kafkajs", "broker": "localhost:9092", "clientId": "nestjs-consumer-server", "error": "This server does noy host this topic-partition", "correlationId": 7, "size": 371"}

KafkaJSProtocolError: This server does not host this topic-partition
....
```

An important thing to say is that the same code and configuration worked with a different kafka stack (I just do not have all the information about the specific image and version of the last stack)

I dont understand if the problem is with the kafka configuration, or if kafka is not allowing consumers to create topics automatically, or the problem is with nest?

Edit:

I discovered that the application does create two topics each time and then fails, so I think it means Kafka is configured correctly for auto topic creation and the problem is in nest application or kafkajs.

Comment: Consumers don't automatically create topics. And even if they did, it'd be empty, so there's no reason to

Comment: My scenario is that i have a consumer for a cdc connector (listen to database changes) and I have a consumer that process this change events. The connector creates a topic automatically only when a data changes at the table of the topic. So how would you suggest I create a consumer for topics that are not created yet but will be created when data is changed?

Comment: I don't know about kafkajs, but non existing topics will be refetched continously in the Java API. It's not a fatal exception to consume a non existing topic

Comment: Hi, notice the edited question about topic creation, maybe it will help

Comment: Okay, well, as mentioned, consumers don't automatically create topics, so something else is doing that. You can use AdminClient in kafkajs to create topics / ensure they exist rather than depend on something else to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a perfect solution but what worked for me at the end is to use Kafka with zookeeper instead of kraft, this solved the error and enabled the consumer to create all the topics automatically. But probably the better solution is to create the topics before the consumer tries to consume them.